# Как можно вывести список всех участников гильдий и отследить на кого нажал участник в SelectMenu?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, npm

уважаемые пользователя портала. Вот как можно сделать как указано на изображение снизу? В принципе, в теме описано то, что я бы хотел.
Просто пример, как это можно вывести, и дальше как отловить взаимодействие.

[image: Пример с выводом:]